# How can i update the DirectoryInfo array variable in backgroundworker dowork event in real time?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a button click event with two backgroundworkers.

```
static DirectoryInfo[] MySubDirectories;
        private void btnProcess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btnProcess.Enabled = false;
            btnDirectory.Enabled = false;
            btnCancel.Visible = true;
            btnCancel.Enabled = true;
            btnCancel.Text = "Cancel";
            MyProgressBar.Visible = true;

            _FileProcessingWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
            _FileProcessingWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            _FileProcessingWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;

            _FileProcessingWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(_FileProcessingWorker_DoWork);
            _FileProcessingWorker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(_FileProcessingWorker_ProgressChanged);
            _FileProcessingWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(_FileProcessingWorker_RunWorkerCompleted);

            _FileInformationWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
            _FileInformationWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            _FileInformationWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;

            _FileInformationWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(_FileInformationWorker_DoWork);
            _FileInformationWorker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(_FileInformationWorker_ProgressChanged);
            _FileInformationWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(_FileInformationWorker_RunWorkerCompleted);

            if (BasePath != null)
            {
                _FileInformationWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
        }
```

In the first backgroundworker the _FileInformationWorker in the dowork event I did

```
private void  _FileInformationWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            MySubDirectories = GetDirectories(BasePath).ToArray();
        }
```

Then the GetDirectories method

```
private List<DirectoryInfo> GetDirectories(string basePath)
        {
            IEnumerable<string> str = MyGetDirectories(basePath);

            List<DirectoryInfo> l = new List<DirectoryInfo>();
            l.Add(new DirectoryInfo(basePath));

            IEnumerable<DirectoryInfo> dirs = str.Select(a => new DirectoryInfo(a));
            l.AddRange(dirs);

            return l;
        }
```

And the MyGetDirectories method

```
int countDirectories = 0;
    private IEnumerable<string> MyGetDirectories(string basePath)
    {
        try
        {
            string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(basePath);
            countDirectories = countDirectories + dirs.Length;
            _FileInformationWorker.ReportProgress(countDirectories);
            return dirs.Union(dirs.SelectMany(dir => MyGetDirectories(dir)));
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
            return Enumerable.Empty<string>();
        }
    }
```

Then in the first backgroundworker progresschanged event i'm updating a label with the number of directories counted in real time

```
private void _FileInformationWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            label2.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString();
        }
```

Now when the first backgroundworker is working _FileInformationWorker I need to wait until the method MyGetDirectories will finish his process getting all directories only when the method is finish then in the DoWork event the variable MySubDirectories will not be null.

But instead waiting for the method MyGetDirectories to finish I want in real time to update in the DoWork event or maybe somehow in the progresschanged event the variable MySubDirectories with the directories already got so far in real time. Then when MySubDirectories even if it's length is 1 or more start the second backgroundworker and work on the MySubDirectories.

And keep updating the MySubDirectories in the first backgroundworker and at the same time keep working on it in the second backgroundworker dowork.

This is the second backgroundworker dowork event:

```
private void _FileProcessingWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            int countmore = 0;
            try
            {
                DirectoryInfo[] MySubDirectories = (DirectoryInfo[])e.Argument;
                for (int i = 0; i < MySubDirectories.GetLength(0); i++)
                {
                    DirectoryInfo MySubDirectory = MySubDirectories[i];
                    List<FileInfo> l = new List<FileInfo>();
                    CountFiles(MySubDirectory, l);
                    int totalFiles = l.Count;
                    object[] CurrentStatus = new object[5];
                    CurrentStatus[3] = i.ToString();
                    countmore += totalFiles;
                    CurrentStatus[4] = countmore;
                    _FileProcessingWorker.ReportProgress(0, CurrentStatus);

                    string CurrentDirectory = "Current Directory: " + MySubDirectory.Name;

                    foreach (FileInfo MyFile in l)
                    {
                        CurrentStatus = new object[5];
                        if (_FileProcessingWorker.CancellationPending)
                        {
                            e.Cancel = true;
                            return;
                        }

                        if (MyFile.Extension.ToLower() == ".cs" || MyFile.Extension.ToLower() == ".vb")
                        {
                            string CurrentFile = "Current File: " + MyFile.Name;
                            string CurrentFileWithPath = MyFile.FullName;

                            CurrentStatus[0] = CurrentDirectory;
                            CurrentStatus[1] = CurrentFile;
                            _FileProcessingWorker.ReportProgress(0, CurrentStatus);

                            List<string> Result = SearchInFile(CurrentFileWithPath, "ShellContextMenu");

                            if (Result != null && Result.Count > 0)
                            {
                                CurrentStatus[2] = Result;
                                _FileProcessingWorker.ReportProgress(0, CurrentStatus);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                return;
            }

        }
```

And this is how should I start the second backgroundworker but not sure yet where to do it I used to do it in the button click event but now I need to do it some where else maybe in the first backgroundworker dowork event ?

```
int SubDirectoryCount = MySubDirectories.GetLength(0);
                MyProgressBar.Minimum = 0;
                MyProgressBar.Step = 1;
                MyProgressBar.Maximum = SubDirectoryCount;
                MyProgressBar.Value = MyProgressBar.Minimum;
                _LastCounter = 0;
                _FileProcessingWorker.RunWorkerAsync(MySubDirectories);
```

The main problems are how to update the variable MySubDirectories in the first backgroundworker in real time and not waiting until the backgroundworker completed the process.

And how and where to start the second backgroundworker and how to keep looping over the MySubDirectories variable in the second backgroundworker from the last point and not over again all on the directories but only on the last ones that added.

Comment: Are you trying to implement producer-consumer pattern? There are much easier ways nowadays than using the (obsolete) background workers.

Comment: Ivan I think yes about implement producer-consumer pattern. But anyway what other ways there are better then another backgorundworker for example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you considered use some public boolean variables? Maybe it can help to knowing when a procedure go ending and must continued another one.